# Are tool fixing questions on topic?

Tags: discussion

My specific question would relate to a drill press chuck that wobbled and possibly damaged itself while falling out. I'm looking for more knowledge insight into if the chuck is junked and, if not, what to do about the fall out.

But, more broadly, are questions involving tools and/or tool repair considered on topic here?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I would say questions about maintaining and repairing woodworking tools are on-topic.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it's on topic

Comment: I'd go so far as to suggest that you can't really have a Q&A site dedicated to almost any hand-craft without discussing tool design, modification, creation, and repair. It's just part of the history!